# How to use useReducer and rxjs with react hooks?

Tags: rxjs, react-hooks

I would like to use useReducer from react-hooks and rxjs together.
For example, I would like to fetch data from an API.

This is the code I wrote in order to do that:

**RXJS hook:**

```
function useRx(createSink, data, defaultValue = null) {
    const [source, sinkSubscription] = useMemo(() => {
        const source = new Subject()
        const sink = createSink(source.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()));
        const sinkSubscription = sink.subscribe()
        return [source, sinkSubscription]
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        source.next(data)
    }, [source, data])

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            sinkSubscription.unsubscribe()
        };
    }, [sinkSubscription])
}
```

**Reducer code:**

```
const dataFetchReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_LOADING':
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };
        case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                total: action.payload.total,
                data: action.payload.data
            };
        case 'FETCH_FAILURE':
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload
            };
        case 'PAGE':
            return {
                ...state,
                page: action.page,
                rowsPerPage: action.rowsPerPage
            };
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
};
```

**How i mix them:**

```
function usePaginationReducerEndpoint(callbackService) {
    const defaultPagination = {
        statuses: null,
        page: 0,
        rowsPerPage: 10,
        data: [],
        total: 0,
        error: null,
        loading: false
    }
    const [pagination, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, defaultPagination)
    const memoPagination = useMemo(
        () => ({
            statuses: pagination.statuses,
            page: pagination.page,
            rowsPerPage: pagination.rowsPerPage
        }),
        [pagination.statuses, pagination.page, pagination.rowsPerPage]
    );
    useRx(
        memoPagination$ =>
        memoPagination$.pipe(
                map(memoPagination => {
                    dispatch({type: "FETCH_LOADING"})
                    return memoPagination
                }),
                switchMap(memoPagination => callbackService(memoPagination.statuses, memoPagination.page, memoPagination.rowsPerPage).pipe(
                    map(dataPagination => {
                        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", payload: dataPagination })
                        return dataPagination
                    }),
                    catchError(error => {
                        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", payload: "error" })
                        return of(error)
                    })
                ))
            ),
            memoPagination,
        defaultPagination,
        2000
    );
    function handleRowsPerPageChange(event) {
        const newTotalPages = Math.trunc(pagination.total / event.target.value)
        const newPage = Math.min(pagination.page, newTotalPages)
        dispatch({
            type: "PAGE",
            page: newPage,
            rowsPerPage: event.target.value
        });
    }
    function handlePageChange(event, page) {
        dispatch({
            type: "PAGE",
            page: page,
            rowsPerPage: pagination.rowsPerPage
        });
    }
    return [pagination, handlePageChange, handleRowsPerPageChange]
}
```

The code works but I'm wondering if this is luck or not...

- Is it ok if I dispatch inside RXJS pipe ? What is the risk ?
- If no, how can I mix both useReducer and RXJS ?
- If it's not the good approach, what is the good one ?

I know this ressource: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/. But I would like to mix the power of hooks and RXJS in order to use, for example, the debounce function with rxjs in an async request...

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a **middleware** to connect useReducer and rxjs rather than create one yourself.
Using useReducer will create a lot of potential hard to debug code and also need an independent container component to put useReducer to prevent accident global rerendering.

So I suggest that using redux places useReducer to create global state from a component and use **redux-observable** (RxJS 6-based middleware for Redux) as middleware to connect rxjs and redux.

if you know rxjs well, it will be very easy to use, as official web show, fetch data from api will be:
https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html

```
// epic
const fetchUserEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(FETCH_USER),
  mergeMap(action =>
    ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${action.payload}`).pipe(
      map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response))
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: is it overkill to use redux when I don't need a global state ? Is it still the best choice ?

Comment: @PakitoSec redux is still a solid choice at least separate business code to a lot of logical files, and with Redux DevTools Extension, it is easy to dev and debug with Chrome. UI components won't feel any complex data flow behind it with rx.js. So even rx.js logic (as epic in redux-observable) is highly reusable. I just refactor my project which used local state before with redux-observable, it just amazing. Other choice would be MobX, but I don't use it much so can't give you valuable experience.

Comment: Thanks I will go that way.